# Erlang: create a disc schema

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mnesia

If an Erlang application, myapp, requires mnesia to run, then `mnesia` should be included in its application resource file, under key `applications`, so that if myapp is started, mnesia would get started automatically - it's node type by default is `opt_disc` (OTP 18).

What if I want a `disc` node? I know I can set `-mnesia schema_location disc` at command line, but this only works if a schema already exists, which means I should perform some initialization before starting myapp, is there an "OTP-ful" way, without removing `mnesia` from `applications`, to avoid this initialization? The main objective is to turn "init-then-start" into just "start".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not correct from your post:

> ... `mnesia` should be included in its application resource file, under key applications, so that if myapp is started, mnesia would get started automatically.

The applications which you write as a value of `applications` key in `.app` file don't start automatically, but it says that they must be started before your application is started.

---

Imagine that we want to create `foo` application which depends on `mnesia` with some customization. One way is starting it in `foo_app.erl` file:

```
-module(foo_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    mnesia:start().
    mnesia:change_table_copy_type(schema, node(), disc_copies),

    %% configure mnesia
    %% create your tables
    %% ...

    foo_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

This way it creates `disc` schema whether it was created before or not.

---

**Note**: In this solution if you write `mnesia` as dependency under `applications` key in you `foo.app.src` file (which in compile time would create `foo.app`), when starting the `foo` application you get `{error, {not_started, mnesia}}`. So you must not do it and let your application to start it in its `foo_app:start/2` function.

Comment: Technically you are right, but if you use release, [systools uses this list to generate correct start scripts](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html), so actually I don't need to `mnesia:start/0` myself, `mnesia:change_table_copy_type/3` works :)

Comment: @NotanID Yes, using `release` is another option that starts dependencies automatically.